# Elastic Search Client with Nginx Vs Without Ngnix

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch

I have one elastic search **client** server and I am able to connect that server using port **9200**, like this **http://myserver:9200**.

No issue so far, but I am confused that why blogs are saying to use nginx on the front of elastic search client. Is it because of **performance/security** improvement or any other reason?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx can be put in front of ES for following security or load balancing

1)Yes you can use nginx as proxy in front of your elasticsearch server to implement security as security doesn't come in-built in elasticsearch. Nginx implementation for security is not much granular and provides ways to authenticate, authorize search requests.

Please refer to my earlier answers for more detailed explanation.

[Restrict user using shield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052645/restrict-users-behaviour-in-elasticsearch/40057475#40057475)

[shield for blocking operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015642/how-to-create-a-read-only-client-for-elasticsearch-in-python/41020273#41020273)

But if security is what you are looking for then i would suggest to move to shield which comes with X-Pack for advance configurations for security.

[shield official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/enable-basic-auth.html)
[Custom roles using shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/defining-roles.html)

Using shield you can define more granular security configuration for your elastic cluster. Currently shield supports basic authentication, role-based access control, [document level security,](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/setting-up-field-and-document-level-security.html) LDAP integration, ssl, IP filtering

2) Some places people use nginx as a load balancer for incoming request to cluster. But here also you can do without nginx by setting up one of the node in your cluster as client node along with dedicated master node and data nodes.
Client node help distributing indexing and search traffic from your data nodes.
Using client node you can build a better facing interface for your cluster for monitoring, bulk indexing, search traffic distributing.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789479/how-to-setup-elasticsearch-client-nodes) is one good answer on client node.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may help 
[Nginx-elastic-client](https://github.com/Taymindis/nginx-elastic-client)

```
location /search {
    elastic_pass http://elastic_upstream;
    elastic_send POST /yourindex/_search;
    elastic_query '{
          "query": {
              "bool": {
                  "must": [
                       { "match":  { "message": "$arg_message" } },
                       { "match":  { "level": "$arg_level" } }
                  ]
              }
          }
      }';
}
```

It structure your command inside nginx config, the query inside the nginx.conf has version controlled, maintained, tracked and it's transparent to every of your team member. Central based and pass to multiple elastic server.